# constraint layout buttons at bottom not visible after clicking a text field

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem with constraint layout. The layout contains a listview above a textfield with two buttons up.
In the preview is alright:
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5790f.png)

though when I compile the app, the buttons are not visible:
[compiled app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tczQz.png)

And after clicking the textfield, making the keyboard pop up and close the keyboard again is moving the buttons up, so they are visible.
But the space at the top, above the fragment tabs, where the app name usually stands, disappears :
[compiled app after clicking textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCoE2.png)

unfortunately I have no idea why and would like to see some suggestions.

**the code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFriendsAddSearchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Suchen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bFriendsAddAddButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFriendsAddAddButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Hinzufügen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bFriendsAddSearchButton" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eTFriendsAddText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bFriendsAddSearchButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvFriendsAddList" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvFriendsAddList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/eTFriendsAddText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use guideline at the bottom, before the 2button widgets. at the given code you are not closing the .

In the compiled after click the view comes up (because you open the keyboard) so it has to be a problem with the marginbottom/padding bottom of the main constrainLayout. It's an easy fix, no worries.

Comment: You mean in the given code I´m not closing the constraint layout?
Sorry about that, i forgot to paste the line 

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: @Bela9 No Worries. Now remove the bottom constrain of the button widget, from the parent. You don't need that. If it still faces problems, then you can re-arrange or just use a horizontal guideline just to keep it in place.

Comment: Removing the 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
moves the buttons to the top, the listview and textfield are not visible anymore.
 
Adding a guideline right at the bottom and making the buttons 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
helpes.
 
Though opening the keyboard moves the Titlebar up, after closing the keyboard the titlebar is still gone, so the space at the bottom is 8dp plus the height of the titlebar. 
 
Also I forgot to mention that this constraint layout is a fragment of a tabbedLayout

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFriendsAddList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTFriendsAddText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFriendsAddSearchButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Suchen"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFriendsAddAddButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Hinzufügen"

        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Or you could use relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFriendsAddList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTFriendsAddText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lvFriendsAddList"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bFriendsAddSearchButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Suchen" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bFriendsAddAddButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Hinzufügen" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```